# Is it possible to catch java Errors using try catch?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Suppose Something like below will through stack overflow

```
while(true){
        java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
    }
```

is it possible to catch errors? like this

```
try {
while(true){
    java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
    }
}catch (Throwable t){

}
```

Comment: Did you try running your code ? Yes. Possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP did not show minimal research.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can catch it from your code. but, from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)

> An Error is a subclass of `Throwable` that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most applications should not try to catch it.
>
> **A method is not required to declare in its `throws` clause any subclasses of `Error` that might be thrown during the execution of the method but not caught**, since these errors are abnormal conditions that should never occur. That is, Error and its subclasses are regarded as unchecked exceptions for the purposes of compile-time checking of exceptions.